# How to get element by name in .net visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I know how to get an element by its ID in visual basic (.net) with getelementbyid.

But how do I get an element by its name attribute.

e.g. `<input id="123" name="**123**">`

And if so, how do I interact with said element.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean javascript's [getElementsByName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)?

Comment: Are you trying to get a standard HTML element as you've referenced above, or a .NET control? With a .NET control, you need to use ClientID (from server side) in a script block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you will need to do something like this:

```
            Dim myInput As HtmlInputControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("123"), HtmlInputControl)
```

Then do stuff with the input you just created

```
            myInput.Enabled = False
```

OR

You could just add `runat="server"` to your element `<input id="123" name="**123**" runat="server">` and then just reference the element by its id server side as long as the function you're referencing your element in isn't a shared function (if it's shared, you'll need a new instance of the class it was created in to reference it).

```
           123.Enabled = False
```

Also, I'm not sure if you're just doing it to show the example, but you might run into some surprises if you use asterisks in your element names due to it's use as a wildcard character. Generally, you want to keep your attributes with numbers and letters (plus hyphens and underscores) only ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Again the assumtion lies with you using the webbroswer**

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    'NAVIGATE
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("whereveryourgoing")
    'Waiting for page to load function
    WaitForPageLoad()

    'Get Element by Name
    Dim fb_button As String = String.Empty
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If InStr(element.Name, "loginBox") Then
            fb_button = element.Id
            'MsgBox(fb_button & " Found! ")
            'MsgBox(element.InnerHtml.Length.ToString)
            'MsgBox(element.InnerHtml.ToString)
        End If
    Next

    '\/ - Perform Actions
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(fb_button).SetAttribute("value", Password) 'or InvokeMember("submit") or InvokeMember("click")
    MsgBox("Done")

End Sub
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection.getelementsbyname.aspx)

Comment: Also, can you explain what the GetElementsByName("NAME") part does? Thanks

Comment: Updated above let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure about the elems. bit. Is this short for something?

Comment: here is you something that was actually writtin in Visual Studio. Hopefully this is clear to the max! Please undersatnd that `WaitForPageLoad` is its own method, and not part of Webbrowswer1.navigation and that this is sample code and will need tweaking for w/e webpage you are automating

Comment: Also this code will work with any xml document ( just remove the webbrowswer object and replace it with the xml file / document ) in the foreach loop and remove the navigation and other parts of the code relating to webbrowswer.